# How can I verify if a method is returning something useful with a boolean is<something> method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean, verify

I been looking around and I am sure there is a simple answer to this but I can't figure it out in my head right now.
The basics of the code I am working on right now is that it is a sequence class and we are working with an array of ball objects. now there is a index that marks an element in the array as "current" and it changes with an advance method or start method. (start makes index 0 current) and advance makes the next element in the array (n+1) the current element (if it exists)

So i wrote a getter method that gets the current if it is within the array's bounds and it returns either "null" or a ball object (nulls can be considered a current element)

But then I have another method that checks if a currentElement even exists... and I don't know how to implement this part of my code. How can I determine if this exists by calling my getter method? 
The way I have my get method is it either returns an element or throws an exception..

Here is my code(Please not I have a wellformed method written for my own use):

```
    /**
    * Accessor method to determine whether this sequence has a specified 
    * current element (a Ball or null) that can be retrieved with the 
    * getCurrent method. This depends on the status of the cursor.
    * @param - none
    * @return
    *   true (there is a current element) or false (there is no        current element at the moment)
    **/



public boolean isCurrent( )
{

    if()

    assert _wellFormed() : "invariant failed at start of isCurrent";
    // TODO: Implement this code.

    return true;
}

/**
 * Accessor method to get the current element of this sequence. 
 * @param - none
 * @precondition
 *   isCurrent() returns true.
 * @return
 *   the current element of this sequence, possibly null
 * @exception IllegalStateException
 *   Indicates that there is no current element, so 
 *   getCurrent may not be called.
 **/
public Ball getCurrent( )
{

    assert _wellFormed() : "invariant failed at start of getCurrent";
    if (isCurrent()) {
        assert _wellFormed() : "invariant failed at first condition of getCurrent";

        return _data[_currentIndex];
    }
        else{
            assert _wellFormed() : "invariant failed at else of getCurrent";
            throw new IllegalStateException("There is no current Element!");

        }

}
```

Comment: `return _currentIndex >= 0 && _currentIndex < _data.length;`

Comment: Ohhhhhh.!!! thank you!!!!